# How to bottom align two elements in a DIV element?

Tags: html, css, browser, css-tables

[image]

I am currently doing this with a table with 2 bottom-aligned cells. I am okay with the table solution, but just wondering if this is possible with  (just css and html, no javascript).

Requirement: 
* The sizes of the text and image are unknown, but the combined width of the two will not exceed the width of the containing element. (e.g. if i later want to change the image or the text, i do not want to dive into the ccs file)  
* Image is aligned to the left, and the text (actually, a horizontal list) is aligned to the right.

**Edit:** In response to Kos,

- the sizes of the text and images are dynamic, be it height or width, BUT the combined width of the two elements will *not* exceed the width of the containing element.
- the image and text should be bottom aligned
- the containing element should fit tightly the tallest element.

Comment: Your description is not clear enough - you didn't mention what is dynamic, what is static, what depends on what. Should the black border scale vertically to match the Image? Is it of constant height and should the image be scaled? Or also bottom-alligned? Etc, etc.

Comment: I did stated that the sizes of the elements are unknown ahead of the time. But i edited it to make it more clear.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <img src="" class="image" />
    <p class="text">Hello world!</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 500px;
}

.image {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    left:0;
    bottom: 0;
}

.text {
    position: absolute;
    right:0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

**EDIT:** I added the appropriate HTML code.

**EDIT 2:** In case the height of the wrapper is unknown (only restriction is that .image has always to be higher than .text)

**CSS**

```
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 500px;
}
.image {
    vertical-align: bottom;
}

.text {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <img class="image" src="" />
    <p class="text">
        Hello world!
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: this is exactly how i would do this.

Comment: What about the height of the wrapper?

Comment: This doesn't appear to work in Chrome or IE9 unless the height of div.wrapper is known.

Comment: This is good, thanks. But just like s_hewitt and Moak said, it does not work without specifying the height.

Comment: Well in case the height is not specified there are a couple of ways this problem can be resolved however you need to be more specific if there are other restrictions you didn't mention. I edited my answer and gave a solution which would require your image on the left side to always be higher than your text on the right side which is always going to be the case judging by your description.

Comment: Yes, I've tested your solution with an image that's higher than the text ("Hello World"). But I still need to specify the height for the wrapper in order for this to work..

Comment: Forgot to click Submit after I editing the original post :) Try it out now.

Comment: In order for the latest edit to work in Chrome, `margin:0;` must be added to `.text`

Comment: Well the margin setting part is optional but the important thing is that the lowest point of the paragraph (with vertical margins) will always be in alignment with the lower side of the wrapper. Its up to the OP to decide if he actually wants the paragraph text to align with the lower wrapper border.

Comment: Thank you, guys. When i was doing it without table, I was putting each element inside its own div. I guess I overuse.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div style="width:400px; overflow:visible; position:relative;">
  <img src="#" alt ="#" style="float:left;"/> 
  <p style="position:absolute; bottom:0; float:right;">Lorem Ipsum</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work I think:

HTML

```
<div class="outer">
  <img src="" title="" />
  <div class="text">Some text </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.outer {display: inline-block; width: 350px; }
.outer img {float: left;}
.outer .text {float: right; }
```